# chunking an enumerable via linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable. I want to chunk it up, ie say there are 500 elements, I want 10 50 element chunks out of it. I tried this

```
        while (true)
        {
            var page = ret.Take(pagesize).ToList();
            .. do stuff with page
        }
```

but that starts at the beginning every time. I am happy with either the above model (an external loop over each page). Or soemting that looks like this

```
 ret.ChunkIt(pagesize).Select(chunk => >do stuff with the page)
```

I would like to avoid something that materializes the whole list (it might be huge). Ie something that did

```
 List<List<object>> chunks = ret.Chunkit(100);
```

Comment: Skip() then Take()

Comment: thats called the schlemeil the painter algorithm

Comment: Not if collection implements IList then it is O(1)

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented something like this for an open source project I work on, made some changes to make it work as an extension

```
public static class Extension 
{

    private IEnumerable<T> Segment<T>( IEnumerator<T> iter, int size, out bool cont )
    {
        var ret= new List<T>( );
        cont = true;
        bool hit = false;
        for ( var i=0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
            if ( iter.MoveNext( ) )
            {
                hit = true;
                ret.Add( iter.Current );
            }
            else
            {
                cont = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return hit ? ret : null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Breaks the collection into smaller chunks
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int size )
    {

        bool shouldContinue = collection!=null && collection.Any();

        using ( var iter = collection.GetEnumerator( ) )
        {
            while ( shouldContinue )
            {
                //iteration of the enumerable is done in segment
                var result = Segment( iter, size, out shouldContinue );

                if ( shouldContinue || result != null )
                    yield return result;

                else yield break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```